# Sed and regex, same pattern on same line two different groups?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have some data looking similar to this:

```
BLACK Harry<-George->Edna<-$$$Tom<-Tom->Phil<-Tue"
```

The data I want to use in this case is:

> Harry<-George->Edna<-
>
> Tom<-Tom->Phil<-

My command, for the moment looks like this:

```
sed 's!.*\(\([A-Z][a-z]*[-><][-<>]\)\{3\}\).*!\1!'
```

What I understand is when I use `.*` (greedy) <s>it takes the longest match</s> and then replaces everything before and after.

So my output at the moment is only

> Tom<-Tom->Phil<-

How can I add the first occurrence of my pattern in another group?

Comment: Use two groups?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'BLACK Harry<-George->Edna<-$$$Tom<-Tom->Phil<-Tue' |
> sed -e 's/.*\b\(\w\+<-\w\+->\w\+<-\).*\b\(\w\+<-\w\+->\w\+<-\).*/\1\n\2/'
Harry<-George->Edna<-
Tom<-Tom->Phil<-
```

- `\b` = word boundary
- `\w` = word character

The best introduction to `sed` is to be found in Bruce Barnett's [UNIX Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to match letters, less-than, greater-than, hyphen, with at least one hyphen:

```
grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]<>-]+-[[:alpha:]<>-]+' <<END
BLACK Harry<-George->Edna<-$$$Tom<-Tom->Phil<-Tue"
END
```

```
Harry<-George->Edna<-
<-Tom->Phil<-Tue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'BLACK Harry<-George->Edna<-$$$Tom<-Tom->Phil<-Tue' |
sed -r '
s/(\b\w+<-\w+->\w+<-)([^\n])/\1\n\2/g  # seperate matchs with \n
s/.+(\b\w+<-\w+->\w+<-)/\1/Mg          # remove the front in each lines
/\b\w+<-\w+->\w+<-$/!s/[\n]?[^\n]*$//' # remove the last unmatch line if exist
```